# How to specify missing feature in coremltools

Tags: python, coreml, coremltools

I have a MLModel with feature names "f0", "f1", etc. Not all the features are presented in the input data, so I trying to call `predict()` without them. In this case I get error:

```
RuntimeError: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Feature 'f0' not provided.";
}
```

I also tried `None` for the missing features, the script just hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can specify `numpy.nan` to indicate missing features. My model was converted from XGBoost. And as the `DMatrix` documentation says:

> **missing** (float, optional) – Value in the input data which needs to be present as a missing value. If None, defaults to `np.nan`.